# R: How to have conditional geom_rect highlights for only a specific string in a column of strings for geom_point plot

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, highlight

I have the following dataframe and scatterplot

```
df <-
    setNames(data.frame(
        as.POSIXct(
            c(
            "2022-07-29 00:00:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:00:05",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:05:05",
            "2022-07-29 00:10:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:15:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:20:00",
            "2022-07-29 00:20:05"
            )),
        c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
        c(0.8, 2.1, 2.5, 4.1, 5, 6.1, 6.9, 8.1),
        c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c")
    ),
    c("timeStamp", "value1", "value2", "text"))

df %>% ggplot(aes(timeStamp, value1, color =text)) + geom_point()
```

I want to highlight on the graph the areas where a specific text value is in the same row as the data. for example, if we want to highlight with geom_rect the b values, here is my attempt:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(timeStamp, value1, color =text)) + geom_point() +
   geom_rect(xmin= -00:00:05, xmax=  00:00:05, ymin=-0.2, ymax=0.2, color = ifelse(text=="b", 
  "yellow", ""), alpha =0.5)
```

I know this doesnt work but can't seem to find a solution. Also, I know it may seem more prudent to simply change the size of the data points and color of the data points but I need the rectangles for a specific analysis with a much larger dataset. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(timeStamp, value1, color =text)) +
       geom_point() +
       annotate("rect", 
           xmin= min(df$timeStamp[df$text=="b"]), 
           xmax= max(df$timeStamp[df$text=="b"]), 
           ymin= min(df$value1[df$text=="b"]), 
           ymax= max(df$value1[df$text=="b"]),
           color = "yellow",fill="yellow", alpha = 0.2 )+
       theme_bw()
```

or using geom_rect

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(timeStamp, value1, color =text)) +
    geom_point() + geom_rect(data = subset(df,text=="b"),
          xmin= df$timeStamp[df$text=="b"]+60,
          xmax= df$timeStamp[df$text=="b"]-60,
          ymin= df$value1[df$text=="b"]+1,
          ymax= df$value1[df$text=="b"]-1,
          color = NA, fill="yellow", alpha = 0.2)+
    theme_light()
```

Comment: This is great but what if the sections that need to be highlighted are not consecutive? this box just covers all the points "b" points because they happen to be next to each other. Is there a way to adjust this code so that it does separate rectangles for "b" values that are separated by other values?

Comment: If you know the different clusters, then you can add additional annotations! You could subset the clusters and use these for positioning (xmin, xmax etc.)...